# How can i solve the problem with input number format?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

people. I need to fix a bug in the input field. I used Regex to format the currency to be like this: (**R$ 1.200.200,99**). I'd like to know what is wrong with my code?. Please!

Follow the code link

https://6fhfv.csb.app/

```
   <InputNumber
    name="topText"
    style={{
      width: 400,
      marginRight: "1rem"
    }}
    formatter={value => {
      let temp  = value+'';
      temp = temp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
      if(temp.length > 6 ) {
        temp = temp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

        return temp;
      } 
    }}
    parser={value => value.replace(/[\D]+/g,'')}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```

Comment: Your parser doesn't seem to be working properly. The regex used to parse comma and dot are wrong, e.g. you need to call `formatToParts` and get the decimal from there, instead of passing in a NumberFormat obj to the regex.

Comment: @EJ2015 I did not understand your idea because I'm newbie with Regex. Could you help me using the code? Please

Answer (score 0):

You are missing onChange handler on InputNumber.

### Edit

In your example you are providing explicit value to your input and if you do so, you have to have some kind of mechanism to change it, that's why you should add onChange handler.

The other way to do it is to have uncontrolled input where you don't track current state of the input value, but rather you can access it via ref to get the value when you need it.

Both approaches are valid and you should choose the one that serves your needs.

Comment: Hi, @Mario Nikolaus I'm using a React UI library Ant Design and it has this method uder the hood. I think so.

Comment: You need it surely, even every example here https://ant.design/components/input-number/ is using the onChange handler, even the official codepen https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001

Comment: I tested the offcial codepen examples without the onChange method and work. I noticed that the function in the examples are used just to show in console the value.

Comment: Read the part after edit, it explains your confusion

Comment: @MrCaji if this solved your problem, please mark this as answer

Comment: Of course it's not when you changed the question :D